# Cross Compiling C source codes on Windows for Linux using VM Player running ubuntu

Tags: c, cross-compiling, simulink

I've a project that has .C codes generated from Simulink Models (using RTW).
The executable needs to be generated for a LynxOS RTOS, I use cygwin, but its too slow, takes several hours to compile & link some ~ 650 .C code files and libraries.

I was wondering if its possible to put those sources & libraries for share on VMware Player (on Windows) running any Ubuntu or any other linux flavor and then generate the executable ? Will this be faster ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ways you can tackle this listed from fastest to slowest:

1. Native Linux through dual-boot and a shared disk
2. Virtualbox/VMWare Player with a distributed version control pulling the sources on the VM's disk.
3. Virtualbox/VMWare Player with a shared or network folder.
4. Cygwin.

The tradeoff between 2 and 3 is disk access. Shared folders or network drives are slow, especially for compilation purposes. I always go with option 2 unless for some trivial thing.

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely possible, although its speed highly depends on aother coniditions. Without knowing any other details, I'd say a native approach is most likely to be faster than a virtualized one.